# Reset For Loop Variable

Tags: for-loop, text, vbscript, reset

I am having trouble to reset n=0 for loop (`For n = LBound(arrFileLines1) To UBound(arrFileLines1)`).

Example text file:

```
7     a2
30    a1
30    a2
6     a1
5     a1
4     a1
3     a1
2     a3
1     a2
```

The following code will find first string "30" and take position starting 7-255 as variable xxx. The first string 30 is n=1.

Next, it's going to `WriteLine` if the line does not have variable `xxx`.

The first pass is fine. I was able to to remove everything related to variable `xxx`.

Text file updated to:

```
7     a2
30    a2
2     a3
1     a2
```

However, `n` will not reset after that. `n` will start at 2. When n = 4 I will get error:

> subscript out of range: "n'.

Is there a way I can reset `n` start with 0 again?

```
Dim arrFileLines1()
Dim xxx'
q = 0
strCheckForString = ("30")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\1234\Desktop\output.txt", 1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    ReDim Preserve arrFileLines1(q)
    arrFileLines1(q) = objFile.ReadLine
    q = q + 1
Loop
objFile.Close

For n = LBound(arrFileLines1) To UBound(arrFileLines1)
    If (InStr(arrFileLines1(n), strCheckForString)) Then
        xxx = Mid(arrFileLines1(n), 7, 255)
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\1234\Desktop\output.txt", 2)
        For m = LBound(arrFileLines1) To UBound(arrFileLines1)
            If ((Mid(arrFileLines1(m), 7) = xxx) = True) And (n>m) Then
                objFile.WriteLine arrFileLines1(m)
            Else
                If ((Mid(arrFileLines1(m), 7) = xxx ) = False) Then
                    objFile.writeline arrFileLines1(m)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        objFile.Close

        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\1234\Desktop\output.txt", 1)
        q = 0
        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
            ReDim Preserve arrFileLines1(q)
            arrFileLines1(q) = objFile.ReadLine
            q = q + 1
        Loop
        objFile.Close
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't tamper with the loop variable of a `For` loop. If you want to control the loop variable yourself: use `Do..Loop` instead of `For..Next` and increment/decrement the variable as needed.

With that said, it's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve with your code. Do you want to remove all lines that end with the same substrings as the lines that start with the string "30"? Meaning you'd want to remove all lines ending with "a1" or "a2" from your sample input?

If so, I'd probably do something like this:

Since you're reading your input file into memory anyway you can do that like this and avoid the time-consuming process of appending to an array:

```
filename = "C:\Users\1234\Desktop\output.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt = fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll
lines = Split(txt, vbNewLine)
```

Build a reference list from the lines that begin with the string "30":

```
Set ref = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each line In lines
    If Left(line, 2) = "30" Then ref(Mid(line, 7, 255)) = True
Next
```

Then write only those lines back to the file that don't contain any of those strings:

```
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2)
For Each line In lines
    found = False
    For Each s In ref.Keys
        If InStr(Mid(line, 7, 255), s) > 0 Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then f.WriteLine line
Next
f.Close
```

Using the keys of a dictionary rather than a plain array has the advantage that you automatically get a list of unique strings.